# Set port for birt report viewer (web browser)

Tags: birt

I'm using BIRT. I can see that the port is evolving each time I restart Eclipse.

Is there a way to fix that ?

Comment: what you have tried? And please add some more description

Comment: Nothing, I don't know what to do to fix this problem. 

I click on view report on web browser. When I reboot Eclipse the port has been modified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in eclipse go to Window => Preferences => Report Design. You can quickly see that there are several sub - dialogs under Report design. Find Preview and Preview server. In the 2nd text box type the port you want to use. [The process should look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cbldp.png)